# vistas en laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo una ruta:

```
Route::get('index function(){
   return view('almacen.articulo');
});
```

És un archivo Index que se encuentra en:
`resources/views/almacen/articulo/index.blade.php` 
y llamo la vista en mi index general de ésta forma:

```
<a href="{{url('/almacen/articulo'}}"
```

Al abrir en el navegador esta vista dando click en la opción correspondiente de mi menú que se encuentra en la vista index general de mi proyecto.
me sale el error:

> PAGE NO FOUND

Estoy usando `Laravel 5.4`.

Alguien podría ayudarme con este error?

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/index', function(){
    Return view('almacen.articulo.index');});
```

El primer parametro de **Route::get** es la url tras el dominio y el segundo en este caso es la funcion que retorna una vista.
Para el caso de la funcion **view** el parametro es el directorio dentro de views usando puntos en vez de slash mas el nombre del archivo sin extension.